# I want to travel the US with ESTA a lot of times

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, esta, domestic-travel

I arrived in the states in July. I got admitted. Now I want to fly from NY to LA in Sept. I will have problems at entering again back to the country if my passport ( Hungarian ) is stamped till October?

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/100002/58919 This may be the answer to the question that you are trying to ask.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you still in the US? Or did you visit in July, go back to Hungary, and now wish to do another holiday to NY and LA? Do you know what ESTA is? If so, please let us know what you understand it to be, as I suspect you may have misunderstood it. Do you know what VWP is? If so, again please tell us what you understand. Do you realise that ESTA and VWP are different? (That last one is the big one, and I have misunderstood it in the past myself.)

Comment: What do you mean by entering *again?*  It seems that you will not have left the country.  Is there something you haven't told us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is too short for SE to accept but no. I am not even sure what your problem is: you are flying domestic so you won't be met with border control and also you are admitted  'till October and you are flying in September.

Comment: so, when we are flying domestic, there is a different passport control?

Comment: @AndrásFerencz When you fly domestic, all that matters is that the ticket name matches your passport and the picture matches your face. It's a different group that checks your documents.

Comment: @AndrásFerencz I am confused -- why would it matter to you if the CBP checked your passport? You are admitted until October! If there is a language barrier, find me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) and ask in Hungarian.

Comment: @AndrásFerencz when you fly domestic, your passport is checked only by the airlines and the security officers as a matter of identification.  There is no inquiry into your immigration status.  Your passport will not be stamped.  You don't even need to bring your passport if you have another acceptable form of identification (but most VWP travelers won't have any other acceptable identification).

Answer (score 2):

When you take a domestic flight, **there is no passport control at all**. There will only be a security check where they check you have a valid ticket (and they will need your passport), but they don't care about the stamps or how long you stayed.

It is only when **entering the US from another country** that there will be real passport control, with your passport getting stamped